# How best to use multiple fields across multiple models?

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have these models and fields:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    name_title
    name_first
    name_middle_initial
    name_last

    address_1
    address_2
    address_city
    address_state
    address_post_code

class Order(models.Model):
    name_title
    name_first
    name_middle_initial
    name_last

    address_1
    address_2
    address_city
    address_state
    address_post_code

class Shipment(models.Model):
    address_1
    address_2
    address_city
    address_state
    address_post_code
```

Let's say, too, that none of these models are necessarily related -- an Order doesn't have to belong to a User, a Shipment doesn't have to belong to an Order, etc.

I want all of the repeat fields to be identical -- to have the same verbose_name, validations, max_length, etc.

I've tried taking a mixin approach:

```
class AddressFieldsMixin(models.Model):
    address_1
    address_2
    address_city
    address_state
    address_post_code

class NameFieldsMixin(models.Model):
    name_title
    name_first
    name_middle_initial
    name_last

class User(AbstractBaseUser, AddressFieldsMixin, NameFieldsMixin):
    pass

class Order(models.Model, AddressFieldsMixin, NameFieldsMixin):
    pass

class Shipment(models.Model, AddressFieldsMixin):
    pass
```

...but this leads to model/inheritance collisions if my `Mixin` classes inherit from `models.Model`, and "unknown field" errors if they don't.

**What would be the correct way to re-use the 'name' fields and the 'address' fields across multiple models?** Thanks!

Comment: You should put the mixins (well those are technically speaking no mixins) first in the inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your models [**`abstract = True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes). Like:

```
class AddressFieldsModel(models.Model):
    address_1 = ...
    address_2 = ...
    address_city = ...
    address_state = ...
    address_post_code = ...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class NameFieldsModel(models.Model):
    name_title = ...
    name_first = ...
    name_middle_initial = ...
    name_last = ...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class User(AddressFieldsModel, NameFieldsModel, AbstractBaseUser):
    pass

class Order(AddressFieldsModel, NameFieldsModel, models.Model):
    pass

class Shipment(AddressFieldsModel, models.Model):
    pass
```

Since these models inherit from `models.Model` as well, those are not [*mixins* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin), or at least not in the very strict definition. Furthermore you should put these classes first, since they inherit from `models.Model`, and if you specify `models.Model` as first ancestor, this will result in a conflicting MRO.

Abstract models are, as the documentation says, designed to make inheritance of fields and behavior easier:

> Abstract base classes are useful when you want to **put some common information into a number of other models**. You write your base class and **put `abstract=True` in the `Meta` class**. This model will then not be used to create any database table. Instead, when it is used as a base class for other models, its fields will be added to those of the child class.